# How much possibilities do we have when generating two words and a special character at a random place?

Tags: combinatorics

There is a method for generating human-memorable passwords, we just need to prove that it is enough strong. Strong means too much possibilities to quickly brute-force all the possible outputs (or other way, ex.: dictionary attack).

**What do we have?**

We have a public dictionary wordlist of **8000 unique words** (one word is at least 9 characters long, ex.: 10, 11, 12, etc., the **average length is: 11**. Using the 26 lowercase english letters). The words are human-memorable, got them from a spell checker, ex.: https://www.libreoffice.org/download/libreoffice-fresh/ - search for "dictionary".

We have **27 different special characters**.

**The method:**

We **select two random words** from the wordlist, **the selected words can be the same**, space is the delimiter, example:

```
concretely paintball
doorframe magnetized
uncertainty chelonian
popularizer popularizer
supercritical liquidate
```

We put a random special character to a random place to this line (the line is the two words and a space between them), example:

```
conc>retely paintball
doorframe magneti]zed
$uncertainty chelonian
popularizer) popularizer
supercritical liquidate=
```

**One line is one password**.

When we talk about random, it is ensured, that it is really random.

**The Big question is**: what is the formula to know **how many different passwords** could there be? So: 2 random words + 1 space + 1 random special character at a random place.

If we know how many different passwords could be generated with this method, we can prove that it is an enough strong method to generate human-memorable passwords or not.

Comment: A formula can only be made if we know how many words with length $9$, $10$ , etc. are available. This is because the number of possible positions of the space-character depends on the length of the chosen words

Comment: Updated the question with an average length of the words, does it help?

Answer (score 0):

$8000\times 8000$ for the word choices, of course.

How may ways there are to add a "random special character" depends on how long the words are, but they're probably usually not more than 14 characters each, which gives 30 positions. There are 30 printable non-alphanumerics in ASCII, leading to *at most* $30\times 30$ ways to put in your special character.

All in all you're sampling from a space of somewhat less than $2^{36}$ possible passwords.

As [Xkcd famously points out](https://xkcd.com/936/), four words drawn from a 2000-word list will beat that, and then you don't even need to require that the words are *long* (and thus more difficult to remember than the simple words you can populate a 2000-word list with).

Answer (score 0):

There are $8000 \times 8000$ **different ways** of taking two words.

In average each pair is ** 11 letters long** and there are two words. There are  ** 23 characters** from the dictionary (including the space). That means we have  **24 places** to put the special character (We can put it behind each character and also in first position).

That makes an approximation of $24 \times 64 · 10^6$ different passwords **for each special character**. As there are 27 special characters that makes it  $27 \times 24 \times 64 ·10^6$ **passwords**.

Remember this is an approximation based on the **average length** hypothesis

Comment: Updated: average length: 11